# Can I add a rule to every input with jQuery Validation library?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) library.

I have setup a custom method to stop people submitting the form with its default values.

```
// Don't submit form using placeholder valeus
$.validator
.addMethod(
 'noPlaceholder',
 function(value, element) {
    return value !== element.defaultValue;
 },
 'Please enter a value.'
);
```

What I want to do is have this rule applied to every input.

I know I could add to it each individual rule I already have, but I was curious to know if this was possible?

I didn't find anything specific in my browsing of the documentation.

Comment: @Jacob Hello there! Have an answer for me? :P

Comment: I have zilch experience with that plugin... sorry!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question exactly, but seeing as you're trying to detect placeholder text, and that jQuery validation's code appears to use jQuery's `.val()` method for retrieving text input, it makes sense to override `.val()` with a simple wrapper that returns `""` if the input's value is the same as `element.defaultValue`. You won't need a new validation method then, as the "required" rule will work as intended.

```
$.fn._val = $.fn.val;
$.fn.val = function () {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
       var v = this._val();
       if (v === this[0].defaultValue) v = "";
       return v;
    }

    return $.fn._val.apply(this, arguments);
};
```